# Can’t put inkwell in hero

Tags: flutter

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
  child: Hero(
    tag: "avatar",
    child: InkWell(
    onTap: (){
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
     child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/avatar.png"),),
    )
   )
 );    
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this code, in your root widget, please post full code and we can help you better

Answer (score 1):

Try to put Inkwell on top of Center Widget. Like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return InkWell(
  onTap(() {}),
  child: Center(
  child: Hero(
    tag: "avatar",
    child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/avatar.png"),),
    )
   )
 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Exactly,I want to ask why this code will throw an exception!